# Flutter (Dart) SQFlite Bool to Int Typecast Error

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, casting, sqflite

I am a complete flutter and sqflite beginner. I am trying to make my calendar events persist over app restarts so I am implementing an SQFlite database. However, I keep running into this error and have no idea what is causing it. I tried to debug this with Phind, a programming AI, but to no avail.

Error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast
E/flutter ( 6428): #0      EventHandler.fromJson
event_info_model.dart:57
E/flutter ( 6428): #1      EventsDatabase.readAllEvents.<anonymous closure>
events_database.dart:95
E/flutter ( 6428): #2      MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:415:31)
E/flutter ( 6428): #3      ListIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:344:26)
E/flutter ( 6428): #4      new _GrowableList._ofEfficientLengthIterable (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:189:27)
E/flutter ( 6428): #5      new _GrowableList.of (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:150:28)
E/flutter ( 6428): #6      new List.of (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:47:28)
E/flutter ( 6428): #7      ListIterable.toList (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:214:7)
E/flutter ( 6428): #8      EventsDatabase.readAllEvents
events_database.dart:96
E/flutter ( 6428): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6428): #9      _CalendarViewPageState.refreshEvents
calendar_view_page.dart:54
E/flutter ( 6428): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Database code:

class EventsDatabase {
static final EventsDatabase instance = EventsDatabase._init();

```
  static Database? _database;

  EventsDatabase._init();

  Future<Database> get database async {
    debugPrint("Getting database...");
    if (_database != null) return _database!;

    _database = await _initDB('events.db');
    return _database!;
  }

  Future<Database> _initDB(String filePath) async {
    final dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    final path = join(dbPath, filePath);
    debugPrint("Database initialized. It is present at: $dbPath");
    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDB);
  }

  Future _createDB(Database db, int version) async {
    final textType = 'TEXT NOT NULL';
    final integerType = 'INTEGER NOT NULL';
    final booleanType = 'INTEGER DEFAULT 0';

    await db.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE $eventsTable
    (
      'summary' $textType,
      'description' $textType,
      'startTime' $integerType,
      'endTime' $integerType,
      'isAllDay' $booleanType
    )
    ''');
  }

  Future<void> create(NeatCleanCalendarEvent event) async {
    debugPrint("The create function has been entered.");
    final db = await instance.database;

    await db.insert(eventsTable, EventHandler().toJson(event));
    debugPrint(EventsDatabase.instance.toString());
    debugPrint("The create function has been exited.");
  }

  Future<NeatCleanCalendarEvent?> readEvent(
      String summary, DateTime startTime) async {
    final db = await instance.database;

    final maps = await db.query(
      eventsTable,
      columns: EventFields.values,
      where: 'summary = ? AND startTime = ?',
      whereArgs: [summary, startTime],
    );

    if (maps.isNotEmpty) {
      final map = maps.first;
      final modifiedMap = Map<String, Object?>.from(map);
      modifiedMap['isAllDay'] =
          (map['isAllDay'] == 1 ? true : false); // Convert to boolean
      return EventHandler.fromJson(modifiedMap);
    } else {
      return null; // Return null if no matching event is found
    }
  }

  Future<List<NeatCleanCalendarEvent>> readAllEvents() async {
    final db = await instance.database;

    final orderBy = 'startTime ASC';

    final result = await db.query(
      eventsTable,
      orderBy: orderBy,
    );

    return result.map((json) {
      final modifiedJson = Map<String, Object?>.from(json);
      modifiedJson['isAllDay'] =
          (json['isAllDay'] == 1 ? true : false); // Convert to boolean
      return EventHandler.fromJson(modifiedJson);
    }).toList();
  }

  Future<int> update(NeatCleanCalendarEvent event) async {
    debugPrint("The update function has been entered.");
    final db = await instance.database;

    return db.update(
      eventsTable,
      EventHandler().toJson(event),
      where: 'summary = ? AND startTime = ?',
      whereArgs: [event.summary, event.startTime],
    );
  }

  Future<int> delete(NeatCleanCalendarEvent event) async {
    debugPrint("The delete function has been entered.");
    final db = await instance.database;

    return await db.delete(
      eventsTable,
      where: 'summary = ? AND startTime = ?',
      whereArgs: [event.summary, event.startTime],
    );
  }

  Future<void> close() async {
    debugPrint("The close function has been entered.");
    final db = await instance.database;

    await db.close();
  }
}
```

EventHandler class -

```
final String eventsTable = 'events';

class EventFields {
  static final List<String> values = [
    summary,
    description,
    startTime,
    endTime,
    isAllDay
  ];

  static final String summary = 'summary';
  static final String description = 'description';
  static final String startTime = 'startTime';
  static final String endTime = 'endTime';
  static final String isAllDay = 'isAllDay'; // Add this line for the new field
}

class EventHandler {
  Map<String, Object?> toJson(NeatCleanCalendarEvent event) => {
        EventFields.summary: event.summary,
        EventFields.description: event.description,
        EventFields.startTime: event.startTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch,
        EventFields.endTime: event.endTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch,
        EventFields.isAllDay: event.isAllDay ? 1 : 0, // Convert to integer
      };

  static NeatCleanCalendarEvent fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) =>
      NeatCleanCalendarEvent(
        json[EventFields.summary] as String,
        description: json[EventFields.description] as String,
        startTime: DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
            json[EventFields.startTime] as int),
        endTime: DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
            json[EventFields.endTime] as int),
        isAllDay:
            (json[EventFields.isAllDay] as int) == 1, // Convert to boolean
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line

```dart
modifiedJson['isAllDay'] =
          (json['isAllDay'] == 1 ? true : false); // Convert to boolean
```

from the `readAllEvents` method.

Updated method:

```dart
Future<List<NeatCleanCalendarEvent>> readAllEvents() async {
    final db = await instance.database;

    final orderBy = 'startTime ASC';

    final result = await db.query(
      eventsTable,
      orderBy: orderBy,
    );

    return result.map((json) {
      final modifiedJson = Map<String, Object?>.from(json);
      return EventHandler.fromJson(modifiedJson);
    }).toList();
  }
```

The problem is that in the `fromJson` method, the 'isAllDay' property was already converted to boolean and you were trying to check whether it was equal to 1.

Comment: Hey Pavel40! I tried your above mentioned fix, but this actually wouldn't be possible as isAllDay is a boolean property that can only be set to true or false. This is why the value is set to '(json[EventFields.isAllDay] as int) == 1' as it will return true if the value is 1 like you mentioned. I hope this is what you meant or am I not understanding correctly?

Comment: Please try the fix in the updated answer and let me know if it did the trick.